# Selenium and TestNg parallel run is not attaching driver to every browser that we launched even though i used ThreadLocal concept

Tags: java, selenium

I used below code to get parallel run work but unfortunately it is NOT working, can anyone help me on this.

```
    public EmergyaWebDriver initialize() {
        log.info("[log-Properties] " + this.getClass().getName() + "- Start initialize test");

        tmpDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();

        // EmergyaWebDriver tmpDriver = null;

        // Driver initialization
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {

            FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", true);
            firefoxProfile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", this.getDownloadPath());

            File dir = new File(this.getDownloadPath());
            if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();

                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isFile()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                }
            }

            String mimeTypes = getMimeTypes();

            // adding mimetypes
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mimeTypes);
            // forcing the downloads
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", mimeTypes);
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

            firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

            // EmergyaFirefoxDriver tmpDriver = new firefoxProfile(firefoxProfile);

            DriverManager manager = new DriverManager();
            manager.setWebDriver(driver = new EmergyaFirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile));
}
}


public class DriverManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver> EmergyaWebDriver = new ThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver>();

    public static EmergyaWebDriver getDriver() {
        return EmergyaWebDriver.get();
    }

    public void setWebDriver(EmergyaWebDriver driver) {
        EmergyaWebDriver.set(driver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly check with link https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/amp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is I have four separate classes to handle my browsers:

ChromeDriverFactory:

```
public class ChromeDriverFactory {

    public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver;
    private Set<WebDriver> drivers = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

    public ChromeDriverFactory(Boolean isHeadless) throws IOException
     {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", TestUtils.getRelativePath() + "/externalLibraries/browsers/chromedriver");
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", Boolean.toString(isHeadless));
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        if (isHeadless)
        {
            options.addArguments("headless");
            options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
            //options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
        }
        options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        driver = new InheritableThreadLocal<WebDriver>(){
            @Override
            protected ChromeDriver initialValue() {
                ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
                drivers.add(chromeDriver);
                return chromeDriver;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

LocalDriverFactory:

```
public class LocalDriverFactory {

    public static WebDriver createInstance(String browserName, Boolean isHeadless) throws IOException {

        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("firefox")) {

        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("internet")) {
            /*driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            return driver;*/
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("chrome")) {
            ChromeDriverFactory cFac = new ChromeDriverFactory(isHeadless);
            driver = cFac.driver.get();
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().trim().equals("safari"))
        {
           /* driver = SafariDriverFactory.driver.get();
            LocalDriverManager.setFFWebDriver(driver);*/
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().trim().contains("phantom"))
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

And LocalDriverManager:

public class LocalDriverManager {

```
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return driver.get();
    /*driver = chromeWebDriver.get();
    if (driver == null)
    {
        driver = ffWebDriver.get();
    }
    */
}

public static void setDriver(WebDriver indriver)
{
    driver.set(indriver);
}
```

}

Then you have to create a listener like so:

```
public class WebDriverListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

    public static int testNumber = 0;

    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult){
        try 
        {
            LocalTestManager.initializeSettings();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (method.toString().toLowerCase().contains("beforescenario")) {
            WebDriver driver = null;
            try {
                driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(TestSettings.getBrowser(), TestSettings.getIsHeadless());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            LocalDriverManager.setDriver(driver);
            testNumber ++;
            System.out.println("Now executing test number: " + testNumber);
            LocalTestManager.setTestName(method.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
            if(method.toString().toLowerCase().contains("afterscenario")){
                try {
                    if (driver != null) {
                        driver.quit();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    driver.quit();
                    throw e;
                }
                finally {
                    driver.quit();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Your tests should call the listener in an xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="4" parallel="methods">
 <listeners>
        <listener class-name="[PATH TO THE WebDriverListener CLASS SEPARATED BY .]WebDriverListener"/>
 </listeners>
  <test name="Regression">
    <classes>
        <class name="[PATH TO THE TEST CLASS SEPARATED BY .]SomeTestClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Then you run that xml file through testng. This works for me. It opens 4 browsers and executes 4 separate test methods at one time in those 4 browser instances.

Note: You have to make sure that you have absolutely NO global static variables. Everything has to be thread safe (like your browser instances).

Comment: I have implemented above concept and it worked launching browser and attaching relevant driver but i am getting below error and tests are failing while it is running and also observed that all browsers are closing when one test is done.... any clue please...*******************************************************************************org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 89: Content is not allowed in trailing section.

Answer (score 0):

@Trinadh Kumar in regard to your "WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //img[@pc-id = 'logo-big']) org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session " error that is occurring. Sometimes this happens when you have an outdated version of Chromedriver. Try downloading and using the most updated version from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/ . Latest version is 2.30.